# reading Unicode string as json object in python

Tags: python, json, unicode

source

```
<script>
var rcJobsGrid = new revit.grid.TableGrid({ id: 'rcJobsGrid', url: '/jobs/apply/ajax?action=careerCenterBean.jobsGrid.onAJAX&type=METHOD_ACTION', hasPagination: true, hasSearch: true, hasResizeColumns: true, possibleRowsPerPage: [ 10, 20, 30 ], maxRowsVisible: 20, maxColsVisible: 100, rowsPerPage: 20, tabIndex: 0, customRenderers: [{ type: 'STATUS_PROGRESS_BAR_CUSTOM_TYPE', renderer: 'com.adp.wfn.customrenderers.renderStatusProgressBar', toggle: false }], parent: 'rcJobsGrid_parent',  onPostRenderTable: 'if(WFN.getWidget("rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete")!=null){WFN.getWidget("rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete").set("useBusy",false);}WFN.handleButtonEnabling("rcJobsGrid", "rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete");',  toolbar: [{  id: '_toolbar_add', action: '', active: false, onClick: '', label: '', value: '', title: '', iconClass: '', iconClassDisabled: '', children: null}, {  id: '_toolbar_delete', action: '', active: false, onClick: '', label: '', value: '', title: '', iconClass: '', iconClassDisabled: '', children: null}],  timeout: 30000,  transparent: false,  widthType: 'px',  store: { identifier: 'id', label: 'name',  gridId: 'rcJobsGrid' , customProperties: [{ key: 'USE_DEFAULT_CONFIRM_DELETE_DLG', value: 'false'}, { key: 'OTHER_PAGES_SELECTION_COUNT', value: '0'}, { key: 'TABLE_GRID_DELETE_CONFIRM_MSG', value: 'Are you sure you want to delete the selected records?'}] , url: '/jobs/apply/ajax?action=careerCenterBean.jobsGrid.onAJAX&type=METHOD_ACTION' , lastSort: 0, sortType: 1, total: 6, tabIndex: 0, noDataMessage: 'There are currently no jobs available.' , startPosition: 1, endPosition: 6, gridExpressionString: '#{careerCenterBean.jobsGrid}' , possibleRowsPerPage: '10, 20, 30' , rowsPerPage: 20, maxRowsVisible: 20, maxColsVisible: 100, hasPagination: true, width: 950, widthType: 'px' , transparent: false, hasSearch: true, headerRows: [ { columns: [{ id: '0' , label: 'Job Opening' , align: 'left' , width: 300, widthType: 'px' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: '1' , label: 'Worked In Country' , align: 'left' , width: 200, widthType: 'px' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: '2' , label: 'Location' , align: 'left' , width: 225, widthType: 'px' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: '3' , label: 'Date Posted' , align: 'left' , width: 150, widthType: 'px' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: '4' , label: 'Job ID' , align: 'left' , width: 75, widthType: 'px' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}] }], rows: [ { id: '0' , customProperties: [{ key: 'oid', value: '46702'}] , cells: [ { id: '0' , type: 'LINK' , action: '#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}' , align: 'left' , value: 'Research Assistant'}, { id: '1' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'UNITED STATES'}, { id: '2' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'Arlington, VA'}, { id: '3' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '04/16/2014'}, { id: '4' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '1010'}] , selected: false}, { id: '1' , customProperties: [{ key: 'oid', value: '46747'}] , cells: [ { id: '0' , type: 'LINK' , action: '#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}' , align: 'left' , value: 'Research Analyst'}, { id: '1' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'UNITED STATES'}, { id: '2' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'Arlington, VA'}, { id: '3' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '04/16/2014'}, { id: '4' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '1011'}] , selected: false}, { id: '2' , customProperties: [{ key: 'oid', value: '46467'}] , cells: [ { id: '0' , type: 'LINK' , action: '#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}' , align: 'left' , value: 'User Experience Researcher'}, { id: '1' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'UNITED STATES'}, { id: '2' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'Arlington, VA'}, { id: '3' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '04/08/2014'}, { id: '4' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '1007'}] , selected: false}, { id: '3' , customProperties: [{ key: 'oid', value: '15082'}] , cells: [ { id: '0' , type: 'LINK' , action: '#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}' , align: 'left' , value: 'Research Manager'}, { id: '1' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'UNITED STATES'}, { id: '2' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'Arlington, VA'}, { id: '3' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '04/03/2014'}, { id: '4' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '1004'}] , selected: false}, { id: '4' , customProperties: [{ key: 'oid', value: '46476'}] , cells: [ { id: '0' , type: 'LINK' , action: '#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}' , align: 'left' , value: 'Summer Intern'}, { id: '1' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'UNITED STATES'}, { id: '2' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'Arlington, VA'}, { id: '3' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '04/03/2014'}, { id: '4' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '1008'}] , selected: false}, { id: '5' , customProperties: [{ key: 'oid', value: '46530'}] , cells: [ { id: '0' , type: 'LINK' , action: '#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}' , align: 'left' , value: 'All Other Jobs'}, { id: '1' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: 'UNITED STATES'}, { id: '2' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' }, { id: '3' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '04/03/2014'}, { id: '4' , type: 'OUTPUT_TEXT' , align: 'left' , value: '1009'}] , selected: false}] , footerRows: [ ] } });
revit.addOnLoad(_container_, function() {rcJobsGrid.startup();});
</script>
```

actually i am trying to read a unicode string as json object so that i can iterate on it,i am unable to perform that

```
import json

v= [u'{ id: \'rcJobsGrid\', url: \'/jobs/apply/ajax?action=careerCenterBean.jobsGrid.onAJAX&type=METHOD_ACTION\', hasPagination: true, hasSearch: true, hasResizeColumns: true, possibleRowsPerPage: [ 10, 20, 30 ], maxRowsVisible: 20, maxColsVisible: 100, rowsPerPage: 20, tabIndex: 0, customRenderers: [{ type: \'STATUS_PROGRESS_BAR_CUSTOM_TYPE\', renderer: \'com.adp.wfn.customrenderers.renderStatusProgressBar\', toggle: false }], parent: \'rcJobsGrid_parent\',  onPostRenderTable: \'if(WFN.getWidget("rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete")!=null){WFN.getWidget("rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete").set("useBusy",false);}WFN.handleButtonEnabling("rcJobsGrid", "rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete");\',  toolbar: [{  id: \'_toolbar_add\', action: \'\', active: false, onClick: \'\', label: \'\', value: \'\', title: \'\', iconClass: \'\', iconClassDisabled: \'\', children: null}, {  id: \'_toolbar_delete\', action: \'\', active: false, onClick: \'\', label: \'\', value: \'\', title: \'\', iconClass: \'\', iconClassDisabled: \'\', children: null}],  timeout: 30000,  transparent: false,  widthType: \'px\',  store: { identifier: \'id\', label: \'name\',  gridId: \'rcJobsGrid\' , customProperties: [{ key: \'USE_DEFAULT_CONFIRM_DELETE_DLG\', value: \'false\'}, { key: \'OTHER_PAGES_SELECTION_COUNT\', value: \'0\'}, { key: \'TABLE_GRID_DELETE_CONFIRM_MSG\', value: \'Are you sure you want to delete the selected records?\'}] , url: \'/jobs/apply/ajax?action=careerCenterBean.jobsGrid.onAJAX&type=METHOD_ACTION\' , lastSort: 0, sortType: 1, total: 6, tabIndex: 0, noDataMessage: \'There are currently no jobs available.\' , startPosition: 1, endPosition: 6, gridExpressionString: \'#{careerCenterBean.jobsGrid}\' , possibleRowsPerPage: \'10, 20, 30\' , rowsPerPage: 20, maxRowsVisible: 20, maxColsVisible: 100, hasPagination: true, width: 950, widthType: \'px\' , transparent: false, hasSearch: true, headerRows: [ { columns: [{ id: \'0\' , label: \'Job Opening\' , align: \'left\' , width: 300, widthType: \'px\' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: \'1\' , label: \'Worked In Country\' , align: \'left\' , width: 200, widthType: \'px\' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: \'2\' , label: \'Location\' , align: \'left\' , width: 225, widthType: \'px\' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: \'3\' , label: \'Date Posted\' , align: \'left\' , width: 150, widthType: \'px\' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}, { id: \'4\' , label: \'Job ID\' , align: \'left\' , width: 75, widthType: \'px\' , locked: false, html: false, hidden: false, sortable: true}] }], rows: [ { id: \'0\' , customProperties: [{ key: \'oid\', value: \'46702\'}] , cells: [ { id: \'0\' , type: \'LINK\' , action: \'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Research Assistant\'}, { id: \'1\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'UNITED STATES\'}, { id: \'2\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Arlington, VA\'}, { id: \'3\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'04/16/2014\'}, { id: \'4\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'1010\'}] , selected: false}, { id: \'1\' , customProperties: [{ key: \'oid\', value: \'46747\'}] , cells: [ { id: \'0\' , type: \'LINK\' , action: \'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Research Analyst\'}, { id: \'1\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'UNITED STATES\'}, { id: \'2\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Arlington, VA\'}, { id: \'3\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'04/16/2014\'}, { id: \'4\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'1011\'}] , selected: false}, { id: \'2\' , customProperties: [{ key: \'oid\', value: \'46467\'}] , cells: [ { id: \'0\' , type: \'LINK\' , action: \'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'User Experience Researcher\'}, { id: \'1\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'UNITED STATES\'}, { id: \'2\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Arlington, VA\'}, { id: \'3\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'04/08/2014\'}, { id: \'4\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'1007\'}] , selected: false}, { id: \'3\' , customProperties: [{ key: \'oid\', value: \'15082\'}] , cells: [ { id: \'0\' , type: \'LINK\' , action: \'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Research Manager\'}, { id: \'1\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'UNITED STATES\'}, { id: \'2\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Arlington, VA\'}, { id: \'3\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'04/03/2014\'}, { id: \'4\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'1004\'}] , selected: false}, { id: \'4\' , customProperties: [{ key: \'oid\', value: \'46476\'}] , cells: [ { id: \'0\' , type: \'LINK\' , action: \'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Summer Intern\'}, { id: \'1\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'UNITED STATES\'}, { id: \'2\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'Arlington, VA\'}, { id: \'3\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'04/03/2014\'}, { id: \'4\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'1008\'}] , selected: false}, { id: \'5\' , customProperties: [{ key: \'oid\', value: \'46530\'}] , cells: [ { id: \'0\' , type: \'LINK\' , action: \'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'All Other Jobs\'}, { id: \'1\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'UNITED STATES\'}, { id: \'2\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' }, { id: \'3\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'04/03/2014\'}, { id: \'4\' , type: \'OUTPUT_TEXT\' , align: \'left\' , value: \'1009\'}] , selected: false}] , footerRows: [ ] } }']

print type(v[0])

str_to_load = json.dumps(v[0])

json_data =  json.loads(str_to_load)
print json_data
for row in json_data.get('rows',[]):
    print row
```

Comment: Is this valid JSON? Shouldn't the keys be between quotes?

Comment: This is **not** valid JSON. JSON object keys must be quoted, and strings use `"` (double quotes), not `'` (single quotes).

Comment: Because there are embedded double quotes in the values, this'll be hell to repair and make sense of. How did you come by this value? Can the source be fixed to produce actual JSON instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i am sure there should be some way to make it valid json , is not it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not valid JSON; not all JavaScript is JSON. You could try to convert this to JSON it with:

```
import re

def repair_json(val):
    return re.sub(r'(\w+):', r'"\1":', 
                  val.replace('"', '\u0022').replace("'", '"'))
```

This:

- quotes embedded double quotes with a JSON `\uxxxx` unicode escape sequence.
- Replaces single quotes with double; this'll not work if any JSON string values contain single quotes.
- Quotes key names; again, if there are any embedded words with colon in the values, these'll be quoted as well and be broken.

For your given value, this method works:

```
>>> json.loads(repair_json(v[0]))
{u'maxColsVisible': 100, u'maxRowsVisible': 20, u'hasSearch': True, u'parent': u'rcJobsGrid_parent', u'url': u'/jobs/apply/ajax?action=careerCenterBean.jobsGrid.onAJAX&type=METHOD_ACTION', u'onPostRenderTable': u'if(WFN.getWidget("rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete")!=null){WFN.getWidget("rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete").set("useBusy",false);}WFN.handleButtonEnabling("rcJobsGrid", "rcJobsGrid_toolbar_delete");', u'widthType': u'px', u'store': {u'maxRowsVisible': 20, u'endPosition': 6, u'gridId': u'rcJobsGrid', u'gridExpressionString': u'#{careerCenterBean.jobsGrid}', u'noDataMessage': u'There are currently no jobs available.', u'customProperties': [{u'value': u'false', u'key': u'USE_DEFAULT_CONFIRM_DELETE_DLG'}, {u'value': u'0', u'key': u'OTHER_PAGES_SELECTION_COUNT'}, {u'value': u'Are you sure you want to delete the selected records?', u'key': u'TABLE_GRID_DELETE_CONFIRM_MSG'}], u'total': 6, u'hasPagination': True, u'tabIndex': 0, u'headerRows': [{u'columns': [{u'locked': False, u'align': u'left', u'label': u'Job Opening', u'width': 300, u'html': False, u'widthType': u'px', u'sortable': True, u'hidden': False, u'id': u'0'}, {u'locked': False, u'align': u'left', u'label': u'Worked In Country', u'width': 200, u'html': False, u'widthType': u'px', u'sortable': True, u'hidden': False, u'id': u'1'}, {u'locked': False, u'align': u'left', u'label': u'Location', u'width': 225, u'html': False, u'widthType': u'px', u'sortable': True, u'hidden': False, u'id': u'2'}, {u'locked': False, u'align': u'left', u'label': u'Date Posted', u'width': 150, u'html': False, u'widthType': u'px', u'sortable': True, u'hidden': False, u'id': u'3'}, {u'locked': False, u'align': u'left', u'label': u'Job ID', u'width': 75, u'html': False, u'widthType': u'px', u'sortable': True, u'hidden': False, u'id': u'4'}]}], u'rows': [{u'cells': [{u'action': u'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}', u'align': u'left', u'type': u'LINK', u'id': u'0', u'value': u'Research Assistant'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'1', u'value': u'UNITED STATES'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'2', u'value': u'Arlington, VA'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'3', u'value': u'04/16/2014'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'4', u'value': u'1010'}], u'selected': False, u'id': u'0', u'customProperties': [{u'value': u'46702', u'key': u'oid'}]}, {u'cells': [{u'action': u'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}', u'align': u'left', u'type': u'LINK', u'id': u'0', u'value': u'Research Analyst'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'1', u'value': u'UNITED STATES'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'2', u'value': u'Arlington, VA'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'3', u'value': u'04/16/2014'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'4', u'value': u'1011'}], u'selected': False, u'id': u'1', u'customProperties': [{u'value': u'46747', u'key': u'oid'}]}, {u'cells': [{u'action': u'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}', u'align': u'left', u'type': u'LINK', u'id': u'0', u'value': u'User Experience Researcher'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'1', u'value': u'UNITED STATES'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'2', u'value': u'Arlington, VA'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'3', u'value': u'04/08/2014'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'4', u'value': u'1007'}], u'selected': False, u'id': u'2', u'customProperties': [{u'value': u'46467', u'key': u'oid'}]}, {u'cells': [{u'action': u'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}', u'align': u'left', u'type': u'LINK', u'id': u'0', u'value': u'Research Manager'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'1', u'value': u'UNITED STATES'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'2', u'value': u'Arlington, VA'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'3', u'value': u'04/03/2014'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'4', u'value': u'1004'}], u'selected': False, u'id': u'3', u'customProperties': [{u'value': u'15082', u'key': u'oid'}]}, {u'cells': [{u'action': u'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}', u'align': u'left', u'type': u'LINK', u'id': u'0', u'value': u'Summer Intern'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'1', u'value': u'UNITED STATES'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'2', u'value': u'Arlington, VA'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'3', u'value': u'04/03/2014'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'4', u'value': u'1008'}], u'selected': False, u'id': u'4', u'customProperties': [{u'value': u'46476', u'key': u'oid'}]}, {u'cells': [{u'action': u'#{careerCenterBean.viewJobPostingDetails}', u'align': u'left', u'type': u'LINK', u'id': u'0', u'value': u'All Other Jobs'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'1', u'value': u'UNITED STATES'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'2'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'3', u'value': u'04/03/2014'}, {u'align': u'left', u'type': u'OUTPUT_TEXT', u'id': u'4', u'value': u'1009'}], u'selected': False, u'id': u'5', u'customProperties': [{u'value': u'46530', u'key': u'oid'}]}], u'maxColsVisible': 100, u'label': u'name', u'width': 950, u'sortType': 1, u'hasSearch': True, u'lastSort': 0, u'widthType': u'px', u'transparent': False, u'url': u'/jobs/apply/ajax?action=careerCenterBean.jobsGrid.onAJAX&type=METHOD_ACTION', u'footerRows': [], u'startPosition': 1, u'identifier': u'id', u'possibleRowsPerPage': u'10, 20, 30', u'rowsPerPage': 20}, u'possibleRowsPerPage': [10, 20, 30], u'hasPagination': True, u'customRenderers': [{u'toggle': False, u'type': u'STATUS_PROGRESS_BAR_CUSTOM_TYPE', u'renderer': u'com.adp.wfn.customrenderers.renderStatusProgressBar'}], u'toolbar': [{u'iconClass': u'', u'title': u'', u'iconClassDisabled': u'', u'children': None, u'value': u'', u'label': u'', u'active': False, u'onClick': u'', u'action': u'', u'id': u'_toolbar_add'}, {u'iconClass': u'', u'title': u'', u'iconClassDisabled': u'', u'children': None, u'value': u'', u'label': u'', u'active': False, u'onClick': u'', u'action': u'', u'id': u'_toolbar_delete'}], u'timeout': 30000, u'hasResizeColumns': True, u'transparent': False, u'id': u'rcJobsGrid', u'rowsPerPage': 20, u'tabIndex': 0}
```

The `rows` list is a key under the `store` key:

```
for row in data['store']['rows']:
    print row
```

To explore structures like these, I find the [`pprint.pprint()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint) invaluable.